# How to use AngularJS routes with Express (Node.js) when a new page is requested?

Tags: node.js, express, angularjs

I'm using Express, which loads AngularJS from a static directory.  Normally, I will request `http://localhost/`, in which Express serves me my `index.html` and all of the correct Angular files, etc.  In my Angular app, I have these routes setup, which replace the content in an `ng-view`:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/main.html',
    controller: MainCtrl,
});

$routeProvider.when('/project/:projectId', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/project.html',
    controller: ProjectCtrl,
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

On my main page, I have a link to `<a href="/project/{{project.id}}">`, which will successfully load the template and direct me to `http://localhost/project/3` or whatever ID I have specified.  The problem is when I try to direct my browser to `http://localhost/project/3` or refresh the page, the request is going to the Express/Node server, which returns `Cannot GET /project/3`.

How do I setup my Express routes to accommodate for this?  I'm guessing it will require the use of [`$location`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location) in Angular (although I'd prefer to avoid the ugly ?searches and #hashes they use), but I'm clueless about how to go about setting up the Express routes to handle this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what your current express routes look like?

Comment: Currently, I have none, because Express is serving from a static directory.  `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I would create a catch-all handler that runs *after* your regular routes that sends the necessary data.

```
app = express();
// your normal configuration like `app.use(express.bodyParser());` here
// ...
app.use(app.router);
app.use(function(req, res) {
  // Use res.sendfile, as it streams instead of reading the file into memory.
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

`app.router` is the middleware that runs all of your Express routes (like `app.get` and `app.post`); normally, Express puts this at the very end of the middleware chain automatically, but you can also add it to the chain explicitly, like we did here.

Then, if the URL isn't handled by `app.router`, the last middleware will send the Angular HTML view down to the client. This will happen for *any* URL that isn't handled by the other middleware, so your Angular app will have to handle invalid routes correctly.

Comment: It should be noted that the use of app.router was deprecated in Express 4 and will throw an error.

Comment: so per @ShawnSolomon 's suggestion, just exclude the `app.use(app.router);` line.

Answer (score 65):

with express 4, you probably want to catch all requests and redirect to angularjs `index.html` page.
`app.use(app.router);` doesn't exist anymore and `res.sendfile` is deprecated, use [`res.sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendFile)with an uppercase **F**.

```js
app.post('/projects/', projectController.createProject);
app.get('/projects/:id', projectController.getProject);
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/public/index.html');
});
```

put all your API routes before the route for every path `app.get('*', function (req, res){...}`)

Comment: This needs some upvotes. Thanks for the capital F correction http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendFile

Answer (score 3):

I guess I should have clarified that I wasn't interested in using a template engine, but having Angular pull all of the HTML partials on it's own, Node is functioning completely as a static server here (but it won't be for the JSON API.  Brian Ford shows how to do it using Jade here:  http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express.html

My app is a single-page app, so I created an Express route for each possible URL pattern, and each of them does the same thing.

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', 'utf8', function(err, content) {
    res.send(content);
});
```

I was assuming I would have to pass some request variables to Angular, but it looks like Angular takes care of it automatically.

Comment: Having the same initial question: how to serve from a node server a specific angular view. But I don't understand the solution. Could you develop a little bit on how you made your route http://localhost/project/3 serving the right view? thanks!