# Catch all routes loading blank page Angular NodeJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I was working on Angular app with routing (NodeJs as backend). Routing through pages works fine but when I try to reload page it gives 'cannot load path /home'. I browsed through and got to few solutions like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222252/how-to-use-angularjs-routes-with-express-node-js-when-a-new-page-is-requested).

My code is

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile('mypath/index.html');
    });
```

But this loads up blank page. Is there any way I can solve this issue?

This us how my server.js looks like

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port
var staticdir = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'dist.prod' : 'dist.dev'; // get static files dir

// get all data/stuff of the body (POST) parameters
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
//app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/' + staticdir)); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
// routes ==================================================
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
require('./devServer/routes')(app); // configure our routes

// start app ===============================================
app.listen(port);                   // startup our app at http://localhost:8080
console.log('Starting sever on port ' + port);       // shoutout to the user
exports = module.exports = app;             // expose app
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index', {
page: 'index'
}
    });
```

then out this into your config,

```
app.set('views',  'directory where index.html is');
```

Comment: app.set('view engine', 'html'); try this as well

Comment: i would recommend reading up on how you render pages in express a bit more in depth.

Comment: I have posted server.js file code. Can you please look into it.

Comment: add these two lines as well,
var swig = require('swig');
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);