# Angular2 MEAN Stack - Using Angular router only

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes

I have a MEAN project using Angular 2. I have an Angular `RouterModule` on the client. What I want to do is making Angular router the primary router and using express router only for some api like "/api/login".

For example, if the user wants to see the products and type `"www.example.com/products"`, Angular router will be responsible for taking the user to this path.

However, in my project, Express router trying to navigate to this path and it gives `404 Not Found` error.

How can I say to the Express: "You are responsible for the requests like `/api/login`, `/api/logout`, etc. If the request is something else, do nothing and leave it to the Angular."

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222252/how-to-use-angularjs-routes-with-express-node-js-when-a-new-page-is-requested

Comment: This gives errors: `GET http://localhost:3000/systemjs.config.js 404 (Not Found)` `GET http://localhost:3000/app 404 (Not Found)` `Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading `